# MYSQL in not work good with JavaScript (phpMyAdmin)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

**I have this problem**

I wanted to start with MYSQL and PHP but I have a error every time I start up phpMyAdmin. I want to fix the problem first before I learing it wrong. This is the error message:

*A fatal JavaScript error has occurred. Would you like to send an error report?*

***Error report***

```
{
  "pma_version": "4.3.11",
  "browser_name": "CHROME",
  "browser_version": "44.0.2403.89",
  "user_os": "Win",
  "server_software": "Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.6.8",
  "user_agent_string": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.89 Safari/537.36",
  "locale": "en_GB",
  "configuration_storage": "enabled",
  "php_version": "5.6.8",
  "exception_type": "js",
  "exception": {
    "mode": "onerror",
    "message": "Script error.",
    "stack": [
      {
        "line": "0",
        "func": "?",
        "uri": "index.php?",
        "scriptname": "index.php"
      }
    ],
    "useragent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.89 Safari/537.36",
    "name": "",
    "uri": "index.php?target="
  },
  "script_name": "index.php",
  "microhistory": {
    "pages": [
      {
        "hash": "index.php?db=&table=&server=1&target=&token=735e3f1541070da86bd49b0135b92e6b"
      }
    ],
    "current_index": "1"
  }
}
```

Can somebody help me

**thanks**

Comment: can you provide more details ? What have you done ? When do you get this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need additional Informations such as how you start up the phpMyAdmin, any changes in user privileges, etc.,

However try to check with new chrome version by uninstalling the current chrome browser and download new chrome version. Or else try with Chromium browser.

Instead of phpMyAdmin, I suggest using other query tools such as MySQL Workbench, Navicat, etc., may solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks, it work. But as you suggested I will work with MySQL Workbench.